# boostrap sidebar collapse in icon when opens first time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 collapse links, test3 and test
test3 is already collapsed so used `in`
test is not collapsed has no `in`

the problem:
this just happen when opens first time I don't know why, the arrow is already down in the link `test` should not, but after few clicks the arrow backs to work normal.

so test link should be arrow to the left because is not collapsed yet, right now if you see is already to arrow down, someone knows why?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/4399/

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li>
        <i class="pull-left fa-lg fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="collapse-link">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample1">test3
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse in collapse-styled" id="collapseExample1">
          <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <a href="#">test List</a>
          <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <a href="#">Create</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <div class="collapse-link">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">test
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse  collapse-styled" id="collapseExample">
          <i class="pull-left fa fa-lg fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <a href="">link List</a>
          <i class="pull-left fa  fa-lg fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <a href="">test</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #2f3f4d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  text-indent: 22px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #455b6f;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  height: 65px;
}

.collapse-link a:after {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  content: "\e114";
  color: $white;
  background-color: black;
}

.collapse-link a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\e080";
  background-color: red;
}

.collapse-link a.collapsed {  
  color: white;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul li {
  list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your CSS, your arrow depends on `collapsed` class (not `in`).

You should add `collapsed` class to you link:

```
<a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">test</a>
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wc4xt/4400/)

Answer (score 0):

insert : `class="collapsed"`  in your `<a>`